# Block IP addresses after concurrent attempts on specific API calls

Tags: c#, asp.net, security, azure

I recently had penetration testing performed on my website and as a result of that there is a certain API call which I would like to implement an IP based form of throttling on to prevent abuse.

**What I am looking for is a way to add and remove IP addresses from a blacklist, that is applied to my azure website.**

I'm aware that it is possible to [restrict certain IP Addresses/ranges from the security section of the web.config](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/12/09/ip-and-domain-restrictions-for-windows-azure-web-sites/) but I have been unable to find a way to achieve this programtically.

Additionally I can't go in and edit the web.config on the fly because that would recycle my app pool causing me to loose session & cache data which could adversely affect users.

I have considered implementing a solution reliant on storing the blacklist on my database but as this is for security against automated attacks I would rather block it before this point to avoid using resource querying the database.

Comment: Easiest solution might be to store the IPs in a cache so quick to read / write and less load and "short" lived.

Comment: Did you follow the link on that page to the [Dynamic IP Restrictions](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2013/08/27/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/) page? Does that not do what you want?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes I had already read that article.
I thought that solution was too broad as there is only one API which is at risk from unauthenticated users. I do not want to risk causing side effects in other areas of the site.

Comment: I've implemented the Web.config method for now with some generous restrictions, as it's quite quick and easy.
However I'm leaving this question open as I think it would be great to know a way to do this for specific API URLs (in case you wanted to have different levels of security in different areas of the site)